# How to remove only one element from a vector with duplicates

Tags: c++, vector

I am making a D&D game in C++. I roll 6 scores randomly, put them in a vector, display them to the player. Then I go through each ability (str, dex, con, int, wis, and cha), and call a function that asks the player which of the scores they want to use for each ability, and then i remove it from the vector, return the value, and move on to the next ability. It works fine unless there is a duplicate roll, in which case it deletes both of the duplicates. I want it to only remove one at a time regardless of duplicates, and I haven't been able to find anything online to do this. Here is the function call

```
int Character::initScores(std::vector<int> & v, std::string ability)
{

    int c = 0;
    bool error = 0;
    do {

        if (c != 0) {
            std::cout << "That isn't one of your scores. Try again. " << 
            std::endl;
        }
        int choice;
        std::cout << ability << ": ";
        std::cin >> choice;
        if (std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), choice) != v.end())
        {
            v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), choice), v.end());
            std::cout << "Your remaining rolls are ";
            for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                std::cout << v[i] << " ";
            std::cout << std::endl;
            return choice;
        }
        else
        {
            c++;
            error = 1;
        }
    } while (error = 1);
}
```

And the function calls

```
std::cout << "Enter which score you want for... " << std::endl;
strength = initScores(scores, "Strength");
dexterity = initScores(scores, "Dexterity");
constitution = initScores(scores, "Constitution");
intelligence = initScores(scores, "Intelligence");
wisdom = initScores(scores, "Wisdom");
charisma = initScores(scores, "Charisma");
```

Also please lmk if there is anything inefficient/bad practice in my code, I have only recently started working on my own coding projects

Comment: On a side note, your `while` condition needs to use the `==` comparison operator instead of the `=` assignement operator: `while (error == 1)`.  Or better, stop using `0` and `1` with a `bool` variable to begin with: `bool error = false; ... error = true; ... while (error);`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just wondering if it's an issue or for readability or something else?

Comment: There is a BIG difference between comparison and assignment. `while (error = 1)` first assigns `1` to `error`, and then the `while` evaluates as true since `error` is not 0. On the other hand, `while (error == 1)` compares the current value of `error` and evaluates as true only if the value is `1`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I get that, that was just a mistake I didn't catch. I was wondering about using 0 and 1 vs true and false?

Comment: `1` and `0` are `int` values, but a `bool` is not an `int`. A `bool` can only have 1 of 2 values: `true` or `false`. The compiler will *implicitly convert* between a `bool` and an `int`. Assigning `0` to a `bool` converts to `false`. Assigning any non-zero value converts to `true`.  On the other hand, assigning a `bool` to an `int` always converts `true` to `1` and `false` to `0`.  `true` and `false` are actual `bool` values, and you should use them instead when dealing with a `bool` variable.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `std::remove()`, which "removes" ALL matching values from the container (really, it just moves them to the end of the container), and then you are calling the 2-parameter overload of the `erase()` method to physically delete ALL of the "removed" values from the container.

If you just want to remove 1 element, pass the iterator returned by `std::find()` to the 1-parameter overload of the `erase()` method:

```
auto iter = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), choice);
if (iter != v.end())
{
    v.erase(iter);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for the prompt response

Comment: and in C++17 you can even move the definition into the condition clause:)